# How can you get the list of open graph activities published by my friends?

Tags: javascript, facebook-opengraph

I'd like to get the list of open graph actions generated by my friends.

Let's say I can post an action like  my_app:read a book.

> > Can I Get the list of books my friends reviewed to create an activity stream (with or without the Graph API)?

The goal would be to be able to recreate the activity plug-in ( http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/ ) but with my own custom design.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible.

You have to request every single permission for each app.

Example:
AUTHURL?permissions=friends_actions:nikeapp,friends_actions:get-spotify, ...

It's possible to do this for some built in actions.

Example
Permissions=friends_actions.music

So you can get music activities of all music apps.

Comment: I'm not interested in getting all books reviews made by all apps but only the one generated by my app. I just gave it as an example of action and object